# How to make my program not pop up as a virus

Tags: c#, virus

So I recently made my first WPF program in C#. But when other people are downloading it thru chrome, it pops up as a "file that can damage your computer". It is a .exe file so I think this is causing it but I wanted to knoiw if there was a way I could make my simple launcher not pop up as a virus. Im using the launcher to run another program on the user's computer called FiveM but nothing else. Idk if this has something to do with it.

Hope you can help me out :)

Sincerely, 
Ossie

Comment: That's a normal behaviour of Chrome. AFAIK, any executable downloaded with Chrome will provide this message (else if you set Chrome to "save as..." every downloads)

Comment: Its normal by default, but a user can change it. Go uncheck "Protect you and your device from dangerous sites" under advanced settings. I reality, users are not going to do this...